# gradle 2.8 subproject dependencies - compile() not found

Tags: java, gradle

I have a root gradle project and 10 subprojects. I want 5 dependencies to be specified in root project only, without copy-pasting them to all 10 modules. If I write:

```
subprojects{
  dependencies{
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  }
}
```

it says to me that `compile()` method has not been found. How to make it work so I should specify deps only in one place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you applied java plugin with:

```
allprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

or:

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

?

Please remember that you also need to add repositories block. It will be:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle Doc Reference: [8.2. Declaring your dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

You must wrap the compile dependencies with the `dependencies` keyword like so:

```
subprojects {
  dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.2.RELEASE'
  }
}
```

This applies to your root-only libraries as well.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, this is exactly what I did - I have just edited my question. Thanks